# ImportModuleError when attempting to use third party library on AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

New to using AWS and Node.js, so excuse me if this is an easy issue.

When running a Node.js lambda, I am using a dependent module, minecraft-query, but when I try to run it, it can not find the module.

```
Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'minecraft-query'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/serverStatusHandler.js\
```

I had followed **Updating a function with additional dependencies** from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html), but it did not resolve my issue.

My package.json contains the dependency reference.

```
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "minecraft-query": "^1.0.13"
  }
  ...
```

and the zip file deployment, did include node_modules folders when deploying it from aws-cli
[image]

Confirmed that my Nodemjs lambda was running 14.x, and my computer was also using 14.x at the time. The dependency is referenced in serverStatusHandler.js, and not used in main.js directly.

Edit:

I used a copy and pasted powershell script to compress the files into a zip that is sent then sent through aws.

```
$compress = @{
   Path = "my-function/*"
   DestinationPath = "function.zip"
}
cd my-function
Remove-Item .\node_modules\ -Recurse -Force
npm install
cd ..
Compress-Archive @compress -Force
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-function --zip-file fileb://function.zip
```

Comment: The directory structure looks very broken, looks like a windows directory structure with the \ in there instead of actual folders with / . How did you create a zip of your code? How does the zip file look internally?

Comment: I used a shell script that I copy and paste to the terminal to put all the files in the zip.
$compress = @{
   Path = "my-function/*"
   DestinationPath = "function.zip"
}
Compress-Archive @compress -Force

Comment: Hmm interesting. I opened the ZIP file via Windows explorer, and saw the folder structure just fine. However, when I created the zip file via 7Zip instead and uploaded that to the aws, it was able to read the folders correctly and the ImportModuleError was resolved.

Perhaps AWS doesn't understand windows file structures cause it was originally made by the Compress-Archive command?

Comment: Yeah, why would AWS support some weird windows zip structure!? Powershell is a mess :D But now you know: proper zip file creation was / is the solution :)